# get Child node from tree in run time eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tree, swt

I have a tree like

```
    final Tree tree = new Tree(composite_1, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL
            | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

I entered tree child by TreeItem class. Now when i am running my plugin i want to fetch the child node ( or child nodes) of parent which is selected. I wrote a listener for reading event occur which fire when we click on some tree node

```
        tree.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
              public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                String string = "";
                TreeItem[] selection = tree.getSelection();

                for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
                  string += selection[i] + " ";
                System.out.println("Selection={" + string + "}");

                }    
              }
                System.out.println(" ============== action listener ==================== ");
              }
            });
```

Now here i checked most of method but did not find any way to get child node of any parent.

What have i tried :-

```
                    Control[] pqr = tree.getChildren();
                    System.out.println(pqr.toString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TreeItem` has a `getItems()` method which returns the children of the item. So you can use that with the `tree.getSelection()` method that your are already using.